# Right justify not working [Python]

Tags: python, loops, padding, justify

I'm working on code to take a user input business name and print out reviews for it. When I run my final loop, I tell python to right justify the reviews by four spaces, yet nothing happens. I've tried multiple solutions and am honestly at a loss.

(Problem area is the very last line)

```
import json
import textwrap
import sys
f = open('reviews.json')
f1= open('businesses.json')
line1= f1.readline()
business= json.loads(line1)
line = f.readline()
review = json.loads(line)
idlist=[]
reviewlist=[]
bizname= raw_input('Enter a business name => ')
print bizname

for line in f1:
    business= json.loads(line)
    if bizname == business['name']:
        idlist.append(business['business_id'])

if len(idlist)==0:
    print 'This business is not found'
    sys.exit()

for line in f:
    review = json.loads(line)
    for item in idlist:
        if item == review['business_id']:
            reviewlist.append(review['text'])
if len(reviewlist)==0:
    print 'No reviews for this business are found'
    sys.exit()
for i in range(len(reviewlist)):
    w = textwrap.TextWrapper(replace_whitespace=False)
    print 'Review',str(i+1)+':'
    print w.fill(reviewlist[i] , ).rjust(4,' ')
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of input, desired output and actual output?

Comment: By "justify" do you actually mean "indent"?

Answer (score 2):

"Right justify by 4 spaces" doesn't makes sense, so it's unclear what you really want.  The first argument to `.rjust()` is the *total* width of the field, and if the string is already at least that long nothing at all is done.  Some examples:

```
>>> "abcde".rjust(4, " ") # nothing done: 5 > 4
'abcde'
>>> "abcd".rjust(4, " ") # nothing done: 4 == 4
'abcd'
>>> "abc".rjust(4, " ") # extends to 4 with 1 blank on left
' abc'
>>> "ab".rjust(4, " ") # extends to 4 with 2 blanks on left
'  ab'
>>> "a".rjust(4, " ") # extends to 4 with 3 blanks on left
'   a'
>>> "".rjust(4, " ") #  # extends to 4 with 4 blanks
'    '
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to verify the output `print w.fill(reviewlist[i] , )`.

the lenght may less than 4. so it looks like not working. e.g. `'abcdef'.rjust(4, ' ')`

```
>>> 'abcdef'.rjust(4, ' ')
'abcdef'
>>> 'abcdef'.rjust(20, ' ')
'              abcdef'
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you actually want to *indent* the text, you can do it with the `TextWrapper` object:

```
indent = ' ' * 4
w = textwrap.TextWrapper(replace_whitespace=False, initial_indent=indent, subsequent_indent=indent)
```

**Demo**

```
>>> indent = ' ' * 4
>>> w = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=20, replace_whitespace=False, initial_indent=indent, subsequent_indent=indent)
>>> print(w.fill('A longish paragraph to demonstrate indentation with TextWrapper objects.'))
    A longish
    paragraph to
    demonstrate
    indentation with
    TextWrapper
    objects.
```

Note that the indent is *included* in the line width, so you might want to adjust the width accordingly:

```
>>> w = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=20+len(indent), replace_whitespace=False, initial_indent=indent, subsequent_indent=indent)
>>> print(w.fill('A longish paragraph to demonstrate indentation with TextWrapper objects.'))
    A longish paragraph
    to demonstrate
    indentation with
    TextWrapper objects.
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it doesn't work because `wrap()` returns a single string that is much longer than 4 characters. Example:

```
'hello'.rjust(3, '*')
```

output:

```
'hello'
```

While, if you do:
    'hello'.rjust(10, '*')

Output:

```
'*****hello'
```

So, if I understand what you are trying to do, you may need to split the wrapped string and then apply the right justification to each string in the list, while you print it:

```
wrapped = w.fill(reviewlist[i], )
for line in wrapped.split('\n'):
    print line.rjust(4, ' ')
```

Although I am not sure that justifying on a width of only four characters is really what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems you're facing here:

1. .rjust(4,' ') says you want the result to be 4 characters wide, not that you want to indent the line by 4 spaces.
2. .rjust() just looks at the length of the string, and after you've run it through textwrap it has a bunch of newlines in it that make the length of the string different than the width it prints out to.
3. You don't want to right justify, really, you want to indent.

The solution given above about indents is correct.

Formatting text through fixed space fonts is very old school, but also very fragile.  Perhaps you could think about generating HTML output in a subsequent revision of your application.  HTML tables work well for this and are appropriate for tabular data.  Alternatively, consider doing a CSV file, and then you can import the result into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
import textwrap
import re

# A sample input string.
inputStr = 'This is a long string which I want to right justify by 70 chars with four spaces on left'

# Wrap by 70 (default) chars. This would result in a multi-line string
w = textwrap.fill(inputStr, )

# Using RegEx read the lines and right justify for 75 chars.
m = re.sub("^(\w+.*)$", lambda g : g.group(0).rjust(75),  w, flags = re.MULTILINE)

# Print the result
print(m)
```

Comment: This may be the correct answer but it is considered a good practice to add some clarifications to your answer instead of just posting a code snippet. Answers like these tend to get down-voted and/or deleted.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic - Thanks for pointing it out. I will remember this. :)